# Golang os.Getenv(key) returning entire env file instead of just the key's value

Tags: docker, go, aws-lambda, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm a developer who's recently moved from macOS to WSL2 on Windows 10. I've finally managed to get everything working, but when I call a lambda locally through Docker, the os.Getenv() function returns my whole env file, instead of just the one key.

Things I've tried:

- Set "files.eol" = "\n" in vscode settings.json
- Set core.autocrlf = input in git config --global
- Set eol = lf in git config --global

I've been super stumped for ages, and haven't been able to find any solutions online. Any help would be super appreciated!

**Edit:** Apologies, I should have had the foresight to post the code and env. necessary to replicate the problem

```
////////////
// Code:  //
////////////

func init() {
    if err := config.Load(); err != nil {
        api.ReportError(err)
    }
    dbo = db.Instance{
        DSN: os.Getenv("DBReadDataSourceName"),
    }
    log.Println("DSN: ", dbo.DSN)
}

// Load ...
func Load() error {
    stage := os.Getenv("Stage")
    log.Println("stage: ", stage)

    if len(data) <= 0 && stage != "local" {
        log.Println("stage != local")
        log.Println("do production config and ssm stuff")
    }

    return nil
}


//////////
// Env: //
//////////

Stage=local
ServerPort=:1234
DBDriverName=mysql
DBReadDataSourceName=MySQLReadDataSourceCredentials
DBWriteDataSourceName=MySQLWriteDataSourceCredentials
RiakAddress=RiakAddress
RedisAddress=RedisAddress
ElasticSearchUrl=ElasticSearchUrl
ElasticSearchPrefix=ElasticSearchPrefix
ThidPartyBaseURL=https://api-sandbox.ThirdParty.com
ThidPartyCountryCode=SG
ThidPartyClientID=asdf12345qwertyuiadsf
ThidPartyClientSecret=asdf12345qwertyuiadsf


/////////////
// Output: //
/////////////

2020/07/13 17:04:03 stage:  local
ServerPort=:1234
DBDriverName=mysql
DBReadDataSourceName=MySQLReadDataSourceCredentials
DBWriteDataSourceName=MySQLWriteDataSourceCredentials
RiakAddress=RiakAddress
RedisAddress=RedisAddress
ElasticSearchUrl=ElasticSearchUrl
ElasticSearchPrefix=ElasticSearchPrefix
ThidPartyBaseURL=https://api-sandbox.ThirdParty.com
ThidPartyCountryCode=SG
ThidPartyClientID=asdf12345qwertyuiadsf
ThidPartyClientSecret=asdf12345qwertyuiadsf
2020/07/13 17:04:03 stage != local
2020/07/13 17:04:03 do production config and ssm stuff
2020/07/13 17:04:03 DSN:  DBReadDataSourceName
```

When I run this lambda locally on a mac, os.Getenv() functions as intended, returning `local` for Stage, and returning `MySQLReadDataSourceCredentials` for DBReadDataSourceName. However, running this lambda locally through WSL2 on a windows machine results in the above output. Stage returns the entire file, and DBReadDataSourceName returns `DBReadDataSourceName`.

I'm super stumped, and have tried everything I could think of, including manually writing \r\n on the end of each env. value. Any help would be extremely appreciated! Thank you very much for your time

**Edit 2:** From the comments

The command I used to load the env. file is `` env -S "`cat env.local`" sam local start-api --template template.yaml --profile company_local ``, with env.local being the file name.

The command `env -S $'a=5\nb=6' sh -c 'echo "$a"'` prints

```
5
b=6
```

The command `env -S $'a=5\r\nb=6' sh -c 'echo "$a"'` prints the exact same output as above,

```
5
b=6
```

The command `env -S 'a=5;b=6' sh -c 'echo "$a"'` prints

```
5;b=6
```

And `env -S 'a=5:b=6' sh -c 'echo "$a"'` prints

```
5:b=6
```

And the command `xxd env.local | head -n 3` prints

```
00000000: 5374 6167 653d 6c6f 6361 6c0a 5365 7276  Stage=local.Serv
00000010: 6572 506f 7274 3d3a 3132 3334 0a44 4244  erPort=:1234.DBD
00000020: 7269 7665 724e 616d 653d 6d79 7371 6c0a  riverName=mysql.
```

Comment: Please show your code and environment. If `os.GetEnv` returns what looks like an entire "file", it's because that's the value of the environment variable.

Comment: I have edited the question to show my code and environment. Apologies for not posting it with the initial question!

Comment: What loads your env file? Docker (`docker run --env-file=…`), or something else?

Comment: This command: ```env -S "`cat env.local`" sam local start-api --template template.yaml --profile company_local```, env.local being its file name

Comment: What does `env -S $'a=5\nb=6' sh -c 'echo "$a"'` print? How about `xxd env.local | head -n 3`? (You may need to install xxd for that second one.)

Comment: **The first command prints**
```5 `\n`
b=6```

**The second one prints:**

```00000000: 5374 6167 653d 6c6f 6361 6c0a 5365 7276  Stage=local.Serv `\n`
00000010: 6572 506f 7274 3d3a 3132 3334 0a44 4244  erPort=:1234.DBD `\n`
00000020: 7269 7665 724e 616d 653d 6d79 7371 6c0a  riverName=mysql. `\n`
```

With `\n` meaning new line. Sorry, I formatted it as clear as I could :/

Comment: I also added the printouts under **Edit 2** in the above post so it'll be more readable. Thanks again for your time!

Comment: WSL seems like a weird place. `env -S $'a=5\r\nb=6' sh -c 'echo "$a"'`, then?

Comment: It seems that `\r\n` and `\n` has the same effect. It returns ```5 `\n` b=6```, identical to ```env -S $'a=5\nb=6' sh -c 'echo "$a"'```

Comment: How about `env -S 'a=5;b=6' sh -c 'echo "$a"`? (Or is it a colon?)

Comment: It prints `5;b=6` and `5:b=6` respectively. The problem is definitely in separating the key-value pairs then I gather?

Do you think it's definitely a WSL thing, or could it be a terminal thing (I use oh-my-zsh if that makes any difference).

I've also encountered this same issue on both WSL and WSL2

Comment: **Update:** ```env -S 'a=5 b=6' sh -c 'echo "$a"' ``` prints `5`!

Comment: Nice! It looks like `env -S` isn’t POSIX and apparently isn’t portable in what it considers “space” when implemented, so I’d recommend using something designed to read that environment file format instead (like `docker run`’s `--env-file` if it’s exposed with what you’re using).